# Java - get a list in a list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a list of students such that each student can have multiple address. 
I want a list of students and for each student entry, have all the addresses for that student.

I thought of creating a `hashmap` with student id as key and student details as value. But I am not sure how to have a list of addresses in this implementation.

```
List<Student> students;
Map<Integer,List<Student>> studentmap = new HashMap<Integer,List<Student>>();
for(Student s: students){
    if(!studentmap.contains(s.getId)){
        List<Student> studentsList=new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentsList.add(s);
        studentmap.put(s.getId,studentsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: If each student can have multiple addresses, you can put the list of addresses in the student class. Add your Student class code to the question..

Comment: yes, i understand your point. But the student list i get initially is from a database call. which doesnt give a list of addresses.

Comment: So what is your actual goal?

Comment: can several students have same address ?   in this case you'd rather consider adresses as objects linked to student by their reference

Answer (score 0):

If you have a List of students you could then get their addresses based on the ID given, provided your Student class had a structure similar to the code below.

> But I am not sure how to have a list of addresses in this 
>   implementation.

Place them in the `Student` class:

```
class Student
{
    private String studentAddresses[];
    private int id;

    public Student(int studentId,String addresses[]){
        this.studentAddresses = addresses;
        this.id = studentId;
    }

    public String[] getStudentAddressess(){
        return this.studentAddresses;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let there is List of Student (List studentList).
In Student Class , I have taken list of Address and Id.
From StudentList you can get info of student and List of Address

```
List<Student> studentList;    
class Student {
private int id;
private List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<String>();

public Student(int id, List<String> addressList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.addressList = addressList;
}

public List<String> getAddressList() {
    return addressList;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setAddressList(List<String> addressList) {
    this.addressList = addressList;
}
```

}